# Removing PC battery while working

Tags: laptop

What will happen if I remove my PC battery while working and without plugging to charger.

Will the PC restart safely.

I was trying to figure out what will happen

Comment: *Will the PC restart safely.* What do you mean? Why do you think it would restart? Why do you think it would have trouble restarting, and what does this have to do with removing the battery?

Comment: It will start as 'safely' as if you pulled the plug on a desktop. So, bit of a lottery depending on what it was doing at the time.

Comment: You will cause strain and likely damage to the components of your computer. Whether that breaks those components this time is something we cannot know. But it will certainly increase the LIKELIHOOD of issues, and possibly decrease the lifespan of your computer hardware. You never do this just because. You choose to perform this action on purpose when the benefits to immediately removing the power outweigh the consequences of the computer being put through that stress.

Answer (score 1):

No one will absolutely guarantee that it will be OK, but it almost certainly will will - although you will experience some (hopefully very small, possibly not noticeable data loss).

When you suddenly shut down your computer, your filesystem will be in a confused state.  Modern filesystems realise they are in a confused state on startup and go through a procedure to get back to a known OK state.  Over time this has become a fairly robust process - for how this process works, Google "File system journalling".